# html is being escaped in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm trying to implement a link, when clicked marks you as present for a meeting. This link is a method in a helper:

```
  def link_to_remote_registration(event_id)
    down_image = "down_blanco.png"
    up_image   = "up_blanco.png"

    unless registration.nil?
      if registration.present == 1
        up_image = "up_filled.png"
      elsif registration.present == 0
        down_image = "down_filled.png"
      end
    end

    link_to_remote_registration = String.new 
    loading_and_complete = "Element.show('indicator_event_"+event_id.to_s+"'); Element.hide('vote_"+event_id.to_s+"')".html_safe
    complete = "Element.hide('indicator_event_"+event_id.to_s+"'); Element.show('vote_"+event_id.to_s+"')".html_safe

    link_to_remote_registration =
      link_to(image_tag(up_image , :id =>  'will_not_attend_event_'+ event_id.to_s , border => 0),
      :url =>  new_registration_path(:present  => 1, :event_id => event_id, :escape => false),
      :remote => true,
      :method => :put,
      :loading => loading_and_complete,
      :complete => complete)

    return link_to_remote_registration
  end
```

The problem is that when I render the link in my view some of the html gets escaped making the link not work.

```
<a href="/calendar?complete=Element.hide%28%27indicator_event_1%27%29%3B+Element.show%28%27vote_1%27%29&loading=Element.show%28%27indicator_event_1%27%29%3B+Element.hide%28%27vote_1%27%29&method=put&remote=true&url=%2Fregistrations%2Fnew%3Fevent_id%3D1%26present%3D1">
<img id="will_not_attend_event_1" border="0" src="/images/up_blanco.png?1198181114" alt="Up_blanco">
</a>
```

Which I think is not a valid url. I wonder why this happens - i call the html escape on the complete and loading string.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're passing the html from from a helper, Rails sanitizes it to protect from XSS. You can override it by returning:

`link_to_remote_registration.html_safe`

http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

You could also use raw() instead of disabling XSS system-wide.

```
raw(image_tag(up_image , :id =>  'will_not_attend_event_'+ event_id.to_s , border => 0))
```