# How can I tell Rails/HAML to not escape a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, haml, html-escape-characters

I have this code:

```
= link_to "unsubscribe instantly", "*|UNSUB|*".html_safe
```

That generates this HTML:

```
<a href="*%7CUNSUB%7C*">unsubscribe instantly</a>
```

The | characters are escaped.  That won't work, as I'm sending this HTML to a service that is supposed to replace `*|UNSUB|*` with an unsubscribe url.

Instead, I want Rails/HAML to generate this:

```
<a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe instantly</a>
```

---

I went to http://haml-lang.com/try.html and entered  `%a{:href => "*|UNSUB|*"} unsubscribe` and the output was what I was expecting.  So I'm guessing this is a Rails thing.

---

**UPDATE**: I tried this on a new Rails 3.1 application and the pipes aren't being escaped -- which is what I wanted.  There's something weird happening with my main rails application that's causing the URLs to be escaped -- looking into it further now.

---

**UPDATE**:
I figured it out.  I had some Rack middleware that was running something like:

```
content = Nokogiri(response)
# ... processing
return content.to_html
```

This was encoding the stuff inside the URLs.  I asked a related question here: [Preventing Nokogiri from escaping characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512972/preventing-nokogiri-from-escaping-characters-in-urls)

Comment: Did you tryed `!= link_to("unsubscribe instantly", "*|UNSUB|*".html_safe).html_safe` ? [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619577/html-is-being-escaped-in-link-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had some Rack middleware that was running something like:

```
content = Nokogiri(response)
# ... processing
return content.to_html
```

This was encoding the stuff inside the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Are these really escaped? I just made a test with rails 3.0.3 (edit: and rails 3.1.1), with those:

```
= link_to 'unsubscribe instantly', '*|UNSUB|*'   
%a{:href => '*|UNSUB|*'} unsubscribe instantly
:plain
  <a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe instantly</a>
```

then I used curl on the page an the pipe seems to be there, as is:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/about | grep UNSUB
<a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe instantly</a>
<a href='*|UNSUB|*'>unsubscribe instantly</a>
<a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe instantly</a>
```

Comment: Weird.  I used curl to test, and the pipes are still being escaped.  I'll try on a new rails application.

Comment: On a new Rails application, the URLs aren't being escaped (which is what I want).  I must have some different configurations or gems in the other Rails application I was using to test.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried skipping the `link_to` and just to create the link tag directly like

```
a{:href=>"*|UNSUB|*"} unsubscribe instantly
```

Comment: HAML will convert that to <a href="*%7CUNSUB%7C*">unsubscribe instantly</a>, which isn't what I wanted.

Comment: How about `a(href='*|UNSUB|*') unsubscribe instantly` ?

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you:

```
=! link_to "unsubscribe instantly", "*|UNSUB|*"
```

(realise that it's more or less equivalent, but might just make the difference)

Comment: Sorry my fault! What i meant was `!= link_to "unsubscribe instantly", "*|UNSUB|*"`

Comment: Still no luck.  Outputs <a href="\*%7CUNSUB%7C*">unsubscribe</a>

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a place to test this but would this work?

```
- html = "<a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe instantly</a>"
= raw html
```

Comment: That still seems to generate <a href="\*%7CUNSUB%7C*">unsubscribe instantly</a>