# Preventing Nokogiri from escaping characters in URLs

Tags: nokogiri

```
Nokogiri("<a href='*|UNSUB|*'>unsubscribe</a>").to_html
# returns
"<a href="*%7CUNSUB%7C*">unsubscribe</a>"
```

How can I get Nokogiri to not escape the pipes?

Comment: Why would you want to produce [an invalid URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)? Nokogiri is doing you a favor.

Comment: Because I need to send the URL to a service that is looking for URLs like \*|UNSUB|* -- they will replace it with a unsubscribe URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri("<a href='*|UNSUB|*'>unsubscribe</a>")

puts doc.to_html
#=> <a href="*%7CUNSUB%7C*">unsubscribe</a>

puts doc.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe</a>
```

Alternatively:

```
puts doc.to_html.gsub('%7C','|')
#=> <a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe</a>
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with the alternative suggestion.  I need this to be html.